# How to fail an azur devOps pipeline on coverage fail?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, pytest, pytest-cov

I'm building my pipelines in the Microsoft dev Ops forge. I would like to make the test pipeline to fail if the coverage is < 80% but I don't find the information in the microsoft documentation.

Here is my test.yaml file:

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest

steps:
  - task: UsePythonVersion@0
    inputs:
      versionSpec: "3.10"
    displayName: "Use Python 3.10"
  - script: python -m pip install toto pytest pytest-cov pytest-deadfixtures
    displayName: "Install dependencies"
  - script: pytest --color=yes --cov --cov-report=html
    displayName: "Test with pytest"
```

Comment: Could you consider upvoting my reply if it was helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should switch to `term` output:

```yaml
- bash: |
    OUTPUT=$(pytest --color=yes --cov --cov-report=term | grep 'TOTAL' | awk '{print $(NF)}')

    echo $OUTPUT

    COVERAGE="${OUTPUT%\%}"  # Remove the percent sign
    if (( COVERAGE < 80 )); then
      echo "Code coverage is below 80%";
      exit 1;
    else 
      echo "Code coverage is $COVERAGE%";
    fi
  displayName: 'Run pytest'
```